# Should Firebase "keepSynced" be disabled/re-enabled when transitioning in and out of the background?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a big app that has a huge Firebase footprint, and is constantly updating to stay in sync with other similar apps and a web service.

The app was designed as a kiosk app, but we discovered users are switching between it and other apps - in some cases often.

While we don't know of any problems, the question came up - when we get moved to the background, should we disable `keepSynced`, wait some seconds to allow inflight messages to complete, then on coming into the foreground re-enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a general sense, I don't see any advantage to doing this.  iOS and Android automatically manage the lifecycle of apps the move to the background.  Backgrounded apps may be killed outright to save memory and battery, and in that case, it doesn't matter what Firebase APIs you may have invoked previously - the app process is dead.  I would just let the OS deal with moving things around and not try to optimize any further, unless you have some very specific requirements.